# Can't get the UNICODE chars

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have encountered in a problem while i'm trying to get the UNICODE chars and to put them in a list. The problem is that i'm getting the hex code of the symbols and not the symbols themselves..
Can anyone help me with that?

My code:

```
KeysLst = []

for i in range(1000, 1100):
    char = unichr(i)
    KeysLst.append(char)

print KeysLst
```

Output:

```
[u'\u03e8', u'\u03e9', u'\u03ea', u'\u03eb', u'\u03ec', u'\u03ed', u'\u03ee', u'\u03ef', u'\u03f0', u'\u03f1', u'\u03f2', u'\u03f3', u'\u03f4', u'\u03f5', u'\u03f6', u'\u03f7', u'\u03f8', u'\u03f9', u'\u03fa', u'\u03fb', u'\u03fc', u'\u03fd', u'\u03fe', u'\u03ff', u'\u0400', u'\u0401', u'\u0402', u'\u0403', u'\u0404', u'\u0405', u'\u0406', u'\u0407', u'\u0408', u'\u0409', u'\u040a', u'\u040b', u'\u040c', u'\u040d', u'\u040e', u'\u040f', u'\u0410', u'\u0411', u'\u0412', u'\u0413', u'\u0414', u'\u0415', u'\u0416', u'\u0417', u'\u0418', u'\u0419', u'\u041a', u'\u041b', u'\u041c', u'\u041d', u'\u041e', u'\u041f', u'\u0420', u'\u0421', u'\u0422', u'\u0423', u'\u0424', u'\u0425', u'\u0426', u'\u0427', u'\u0428', u'\u0429', u'\u042a', u'\u042b', u'\u042c', u'\u042d', u'\u042e', u'\u042f', u'\u0430', u'\u0431', u'\u0432', u'\u0433', u'\u0434', u'\u0435', u'\u0436', u'\u0437', u'\u0438', u'\u0439', u'\u043a', u'\u043b', u'\u043c', u'\u043d', u'\u043e', u'\u043f', u'\u0440', u'\u0441', u'\u0442', u'\u0443', u'\u0444', u'\u0445', u'\u0446', u'\u0447', u'\u0448', u'\u0449', u'\u044a', u'\u044b']
```

Answer (score 1):

You *did* get unicode characters.

However, Python is showing you unicode literal escapes, to make debugging easier. Those `u'\u03e8'` values are *still* one-character unicoe strings though.

Try printing the individual values in your list:

```
>>> print KeysLst[0]
Ϩ
>>> print KeysLst[1]
ϩ
>>> KeysLst[0]
u'\u03e8'
>>> KeysLst[1]
u'\u03e9'
```

The unicode escape representation is used for *any* codepoint outside of the printable ASCII range:

```
>>> u'A'
u'A'
>>> u'\n'
u'\n'
>>> u'\x86'
u'\x86'
>>> u'\u0025'
u'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print a list, you get the repr of the elements inside the list (surrounded by brackets and delimited by a comma).

If you are trying to print the unicode glyphs, try

```
KeysLst = []
for i in range(1000, 1100):
    char = unichr(i)
    KeysLst.append(char)

for char in KeysLst:
    print char,
```

which yields

```
Ϩ ϩ Ϫ ϫ Ϭ ϭ Ϯ ϯ ϰ ϱ ϲ ϳ ϴ ϵ ϶ Ϸ ϸ Ϲ Ϻ ϻ ϼ Ͻ Ͼ Ͽ Ѐ Ё Ђ Ѓ Є Ѕ І Ї Ј Љ Њ Ћ Ќ Ѝ Ў Џ А Б В Г Д Е Ж З И Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ Ы Ь Э Ю Я а б в г д е ж з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ц ч ш щ ъ ы
```